# Xcode game template project not working in simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, opengl-es, ios-simulator

I found out that the new freshly created Game project template is not working if I select OpenGL, Swift language and run on the iPhone 5 simulator (and older). It is working fine on newer devices or if I use ObjC. Does anybody have the same experience? Thanks

Xcode Version 7.1 (7B91b)

OS X 10.11.1

screenshot:
[image]

Comment: I am seeing the same results.  It might be a 32-bit vs. 64-bit system thing.  It doesn't work in iPad 2, but does work on iPad Air as well.

Comment: Thank you. Please can you try it on real device?

Comment: It works on an iPod touch 5, which is a 32-bit device.  The device is running iOS 9.0.2.

Comment: It works on the iPod touch 5 with iOS 9.1 installed.  This may just be a simulator problem.